# Не понимаю почему не работают корутина в игре на Unit

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerFire : MonoBehaviour, IFire
{
    private readonly Rigidbody2D _bullet;
    private readonly Transform _barrel;
    private readonly float _force;
    private readonly float _fireRate;
    public PlayerFire(Rigidbody2D bullet, Transform barrel, float force, float fireRate)
    {
        _bullet = bullet;
        _barrel = barrel;
        _force = force;
        _fireRate = fireRate;
    }
    public void Fire(float fireButton)
    {
        if (fireButton == 1)
        {
            StartCoroutine(FireWithRate());
        }
    }
    private IEnumerator FireWithRate()
    {
        var temAmmunition = Instantiate(_bullet, _barrel.position, _barrel.rotation);
        temAmmunition.AddForce(_barrel.up * _force);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }

}
```

Не понимаю почему выбрасывает

```
NullReferenceException
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine (System.Collections.IEnumerator routine) (at <d3b66f0ad4e34a55b6ef91ab84878193>:0)
PlayerFire.Fire (System.Single fireButton) (at Assets/PlayerFire.cs:22)
Ship.Fire (System.Single fireButton) (at Assets/Ship.cs:44)
Player.Update () (at Assets/Player.cs:48)
```

Все ссылки переданы, все объекты у класса есть, но работать не хочет(

Comment: Возможно здесь будет ответ на ваш вопрос: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1268964/nullreferenceexception-unityenginemonobehavioursta.html

Comment: Конструкторы у MonoBehaviour не работают. Либо метод инициализации делать и через него зависимости передавать, либо поля делать сериализуемыми и в инспекторе пхать туда все, что нужно.

Comment: @KOTlK Нормально вроде всё работает. Без корутин все ок

Comment: Крч, парни, не работайте с корутинами в таком контексте! Сделал обычный таймер и все заработало))))

Comment: Так ты, кроме как в этой корутине, нигде не используешь те объекты, которые ты через конструктор пытаешься передать. Во всех полях, которые ты в конструкторе присваиваешь, находится null.

Comment: @KOTlK, сделал через таймер - все заработало. Все хорошо передаётся. Проблема в корутине.

Comment: Ты через new создаешь инстанс MonoBehaviour?

Comment: @KOTlK Да, в root классе

Comment: Иде и сам юнити не пишут, что так делать не надо? Если MonoBehaviour нужен только для того, чтобы корутина работала, то лучше тогда через таски делать и не наследоваться от него. Все, что наследуется от MonoBehaviour нужно вешать на объект на сцене, нормально создавать объект через new не получится. Поэтому либо используй AddComponent и потом вызывай метод инициализации, либо инстанциируй через Object.Instantiate и так же метод инициализации.

Comment: @KOTlK она для instantiate нужна

Comment: Я же написал. UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate напрямую вызывай